# Using induction for sequences defined by recursion, such as $a_{n+1} = \frac14(a_n^2 +3)$

Tags: real-analysis, induction, recurrence-relations

Let the sequence $\{a_n\}$ be defined by $a_{n+1} = \frac14(a_n^2 +3)$. We want to prove that if the first term  $a_1$  is between $0$ and $1$ then the sequence converges.

My question is why do we have to use induction **twice**. First by induction we show $a_n$ is between $0$ and $1$, but then induction is used again to show that the sequence is increasing and hence converges by MCT. But can't we deduce immediately that since $$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac14 (a_{n}-1)( a_{n}-3 )$$ and since $a_n$ is between $0$ and $1$ for all $n$ hence $a_{n+1}-a_n$ is greater than $0$ for all $n$ and hence increasing? Why do all books use induction in the second part also?

Comment: Assuming you mean $a_{n+1}=\frac14(a_{n^2}+3)$, it is still unclear what your question is, what you have done so far on it, and where you seek help..

Comment: Please use latex when posting. See here http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Sorry for being unclear ...The whole of a sub n is squared

Comment: I reformatted the formulas in your post; please check they are what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks; actually I meant a sub n minus the NUMBER 1  TIMES a sub n minus the NUMBER 3

Comment: Corrected (I think). You can also [edit] your question, when doing so you will see how the formulas were types.

Comment: yes your reasoning is correct you dont need induction here

Comment: "but then induction is used again to show that the sequence is increasing" By whom?

Comment: most text books on elementary analysis

Comment: This is wonderfully vague (but my guess is that you will not bother to make it more precise). (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Answer (score 1):

Observe that: $0<a_{n+1} = \dfrac{a_n^2+3}{4} < \dfrac{1+3}{4} = 1$ by induction. And you proved that $\{a_n\}$ is increasing by induction as well. Thus it converges to $L$ such that:
$L = \dfrac{L^2+3}{4} \to L^2-4L+3=0\to L = 1,3$. But we rule out $L=3$ since $L\leq 1$. So $L = 1$.

**Note:** To prove the sequence increases there are two ways: by using boundedness, or by using induction. Induction seems to be more popular. Here is how:

$a_{n+1}-a_n = \dfrac{a_n^2+3}{4}-\dfrac{a_{n-1}^2+3}{4}=\dfrac{(a_n+a_{n-1})(a_n-a_{n-1})}{4}>0$ since $a_n-a_{n-1} > 0$ by inductive step.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse ..I can see why the limit is L actually , but your first sentence proves boundedness by induction ,my question was cant we reason from boundedness that the sequence is increasing without using induction again??

Comment: Thanks again for your response I just wonder why all the books I have  read on this topic do induction again on the decreasing or increasing part , maybe the authors want to make a hard subject even harder??

Comment: "all the books I have read on this topic do induction again on the decreasing or increasing part" Which books? "maybe the authors want to make a hard subject even harder" Suuuure.